# How can I forward a SignalWire call to a Relay application from a PHP LaML webhook, and handle it in a JavaScript-based Relay application?

Tags: javascript, xml, signalwire, signalwire-api

I'm developing a PHP application that utilizes SignalWire for handling incoming calls. I've set up a LaML webhook in PHP, and when a call is received, it triggers the webhook successfully. Additionally, based on the webhook response, I've configured SignalWire to forward the call to a SIP.

My current setup works well up to this point.

Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on How can I create the XML file for forword call to a Relay topic?

If anyone has experience or can provide code examples, documentation references Please provide the details.
Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option would be to use a Domain App. Inside your SignalWire dashboard, you can click on SIP and go to Domain Apps. Give your app a name and URL and choose to handle the call using a Relay Application along with whatever contexts you want to use. All your PHP app needs to do is dial your domain app in the same way you're forwarding calls to SIP. Here's some more docs on Domain Apps:

https://developer.signalwire.com/guides/sip-domain-applications